# Is there any firefox plugin that lets me know how much time I spend on internet, categorized by sites, time etc

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

So I can understand how much time i spend on social sites like facebook or flickr, how much time is on mails. etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) [MeeTimer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/meetimer/)

It records where you spend your time online.
It does it in a rather useful way, by allowing you to group websites into activities

[image]

---

2) [TimeTracker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1887)

Features:

> **Tracks** browsing time across sessions
>
> **Pauses** automatically when you stop
>   browsing
>
> **Reset** counter
>
> **Pause toggle** per window
>
> **List** 'work' sites that should not
>   count
>
> **Tooltip** showing total time today,
>   since last reset and since installing.

### Options Window

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

check this : 
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-tools-to-track-how-you-spend-time-online/

Answer (score 1):

I think that pageaddict will do the trick

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3685

But it seems it is only working with FF3.0